# Android studio! Add, Edit and Delete records using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I am an extreme beginner at android studio and using JavaScript, so still learning and trying to grasp new concepts of android studio as a whole.

I am trying to create a database where it adds, edits and deletes records that a user manually inputs.

When I try to add a new record from the friends.xml page it seems to not come up with any records on the view data page. **It doesn't seem to record the data entry?**

**friends.java** (page does that most of the handling)

```
    package com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class friends extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "friends";

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private Button addbutton, viewdatabutton;
    private EditText firstnameinput, lastnameinput, ageinput, addressinput;





    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // SPINNER
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //// END SPINNER
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);

        // DECLARE EDIT TEXT'S

        firstnameinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnameinput);
        lastnameinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastnameinput);
        ageinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageinput);
        addressinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressinput);

        //DECLARE BUTTONS
        addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        viewdatabutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewdatabutton);

        //DECLARE SPINNER
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.male_female);

        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);




        // ADD BUTTON



        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean addOK = true;
                int age_as_int = -1;

                String firstName = firstnameinput.getText().toString();
                String lastName = lastnameinput.getText().toString();
                String age = ageinput.getText().toString();
                String address = addressinput.getText().toString();

                if (firstName.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    firstnameinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                if (lastName.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    lastnameinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                if (age.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    ageinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                if (address.length() != 0) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    addressinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                try {
                    age_as_int = Integer.parseInt(age);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter a valid Number in this field!");
                    ageinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }

                if (addOK) {
                    AddData(firstName,lastName,"????",age_as_int,address);
                    toastMessage("Friend Added!");
                }

            }
        }); // end addbutton onclicklistener






        // VIEW DATA BUTTON >>>> LINKS TO viewdata.xml (listview)



        viewdatabutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(friends.this, listdata.class );
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });





/*
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
*/



        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //SPINNER
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.male_female); //id of the spinner
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.male_female,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                              }

                                              @Override
                                              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                                              }
                                          });


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //// END SPINNER
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


    }  // ON CREATE CLOSE















    *// ADD DATA

    public void AddData(String firstName, String lastName, String s, int age_as_int, String newEntry) {
        boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry);

        if (insertData) {
            toastMessage("Data Successfully Added!");
        } else {
                toastMessage("Something has gone wrong :(");
            }
        }*














    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */


    private void toastMessage (String message){
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }




    // GO TO SECOND PAGE (index.XML)
    //also add on " android:onClick="gotoHome" " in the xml with the name matching the void action.

    public void gotoHome (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, index.class); // go to index.class (index.xml)
        startActivity(intent);
    }




} // END CLASS
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "firstname";
    private static final String COL2 = "lastname";
    private static final String COL3 = "malefemale";
    private static final String COL4 = "age";
    private static final String COL5 = "address";


    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        //
        // 
        contentValues.put(COL1, item);
        contentValues.put(COL2, item);
        contentValues.put(COL3, item);
        contentValues.put(COL4, item);
        contentValues.put(COL5, item);

        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted inorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == 1)
            return false;
        else {
            return true;
        }


    } //end addData

    /**
     * Returns al data from DB
     */

    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Returns ID that matches the name
     * searches the DB and returns the ID associated with that name
     */

    public Cursor getItemID(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +  // SELECT ID FROM DB
                " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";             // WHERE THE LAST NAME = NAME SELECTED

        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * UPDATES THE NAME
     *
     * UPDATE TABLE > SET LASTNNAME(COL2) = newName = WHERE id = id in Question = AND LASTNAME(COL2) = oldName (was previously) >
     */
    public void updateName (String newName, int id, String oldName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 +
                " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + oldName + "'";

        //LOGS THE NEW NAME
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting name to " + newName); // NEW NAME CHANGING IT TO
        db.execSQL(query); // EXECUTE QUERY
    }

    /**
     * DELETE FROM DATABASE
     * >>> DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id = id passed AND name = name passed
     *
     */
        public void deleteName(int id, String name){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                    + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                    " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";

            Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
            Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + name + " from database.");
            db.execSQL(query); // EXECUTE QUERY
        }


}
```

EDIT: this is the error found in logcat:

```
        09-09 22:42:05.216 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting address=cht lastname=cht firstname=cht age=cht malefemale=cht
                                                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table friends_table has no column named address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO friends_table(address,lastname,firstname,age,malefemale) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.DatabaseHelper.addData(DatabaseHelper.java:57)  // ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends.AddData(friends.java:168) // ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends$1.onClick(friends.java:73) // ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-09 22:42:05.218 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment D/DatabaseHelper: addData: Adding ffff to friends_table
09-09 22:42:05.218 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/SQLiteLog: (1) table friends_table has no column named address
09-09 22:42:05.219 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting address=ffff lastname=ffff firstname=ffff age=ffff malefemale=ffff
                                                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table friends_table has no column named address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO friends_table(address,lastname,firstname,age,malefemale) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.DatabaseHelper.addData(DatabaseHelper.java:57) // ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends.AddData(friends.java:168) // ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends$1.onClick(friends.java:80) // ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-09 22:42:05.223 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment D/DatabaseHelper: addData: Adding Name to friends_table
09-09 22:42:05.223 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/SQLiteLog: (1) table friends_table has no column named address
09-09 22:42:05.223 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting address=Name lastname=Name firstname=Name age=Name malefemale=Name
                                                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table friends_table has no column named address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO friends_table(address,lastname,firstname,age,malefemale) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.DatabaseHelper.addData(DatabaseHelper.java:57) // ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends.AddData(friends.java:168) // ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends$1.onClick(friends.java:87) // ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-09 22:42:05.224 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment D/DatabaseHelper: addData: Adding Name to friends_table
09-09 22:42:05.224 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/SQLiteLog: (1) table friends_table has no column named address
09-09 22:42:05.224 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting address=Name lastname=Name firstname=Name age=Name malefemale=Name
                                                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table friends_table has no column named address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO friends_table(address,lastname,firstname,age,malefemale) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.DatabaseHelper.addData(DatabaseHelper.java:57) //ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends.AddData(friends.java:168) //ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends$1.onClick(friends.java:93) //ERROR SEEMS TO APPEAR HERE
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It would be great if the answer would be put as simply as possible as I am still a beginner!

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to use breakpoints? Do you know how to look at the log (i.e. click on the Android Monitor button at the bottom)? You really need to narrow down where the error is happening.

Comment: @MikeT I've tried looking at the logcat and have a vague idea on how to read it.. I've clicked on the blue hyperlink in the "beginning of crash" section and it appears as "(index.java:60)".

Comment: @MikeT .. it refers to this part of the code:

    // GO TO SECOND PAGE (friends.XML)
    //also add on " android:onClick="gotoHome" " in the xml with the name matching the void action.

    public void goNowTo (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, friends.class); // go to index.class (index.xml)
        startActivity(intent);
    }


in the index.java file

Comment: Around the hyperlink it will be brown text, at the start will be something that says exception, copy all the brown text and copy and paste that into your question, select it all and click on the {} button to format it as code.

Comment: Oh, instead of trying to start index activity try `finish()`. This should return you to index (you may be trying to start the index activity which is just paused) i.e instead of `public void gotoHome (View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, index.class); // go to index.class (index.xml)
            startActivity(intent);
        }` code `public void gotoHome (View view) {
            finsih();
        }`

Comment: @MikeT  so I'm trying to get to friends.xml (the friends.class file). I tried putting the above code in but it just returns to the page it's already on (index.xml). The error occurs when I try to go to the friends.xml page from index.xml.

I placed the brown error text in the question above.

Comment: Looking at it now. See you already learning to read logs (i.e. you know to put up friends.xml). Did you get rid of manifest? If so add it back in (although I though i checked it)

Comment: @MikeT  Sorry haha I was starting to reach my word limit. Re-added :)

Comment: @MikeT  ... Slowly but surely!

Comment: always steep learning curve. Anyway pretty sure issue is with manifest in that friends isn't in it (swear i check that it was, because i recall seeing that index was you main/first activity). **`Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`**

Comment: yep add `<activity android:name=".friends"></activity>` to manifest, save and retry.

Comment: @MikeT   worked! Now the error seems to lie in the DatabaseHelper.java & friends.java files. I replaced the error log in the question

Comment: Ok looking again.

Comment: @MikeT when on the friends.xml screen and I go to add data. It comes up with "Data successfully added!" suggesting the data has been added but when I go to click on the "VIEW DATA" button, it navigates to view_data.xml but doesn't come up with the saved records?

Comment: After line `Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();` add a line `Log.d("CURSORCOUNT","Number of rows in Cursor = "Integer.toString(data.getCount());`. Run, look for line in log. If it's 0 then you won;t see anything and the issue is with getting the data. If > 0 then issue is with adpater. Let me know. Uhhm if 0, then you very likely have no data.

Comment: PS pretty sure you have no data, else it will fail at `listData.add(data.getString(2));` as you only have 2 columns (0 (ID or _id) and 1 (lastname)). You'll get some column index message. Additionally it's best to not use hard coded offsets, rather use the column name to get the index e.g. `listData.add(data.getString(getColumnIndex("lastname")));` PPS I need to go and do HouseSlave stuff for a while. I'd suggest asking a new question in regard to where you are now.

Comment: just added fixes for the last issue (a bit long winded). Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the log, it says

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment/com.example.chris.mo‌​bileappsassignment.f‌​riends}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Accorging to your mainfest there is no `<activity android:name=".friends"></activity>` entry.

So you need to change :-

```
    <activity android:name=".listdata"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".EditDataActivity"></activity>
```

to be

```
    <activity android:name=".friends"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".listdata"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".EditDataActivity"></activity>
```

---

#### Second issue is that you have `ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

`AUTOINCREMENT` can only be coded with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it changes the way the unique rowid (a long integer) is generated. SQLite (unless you code WITHOUT ROWID) always creates a column that uniquely identifies a row. AUTOINCREMENT says to a) never use a lower number or a previously used number, whilst without. previously used but available numbers can be used (very unlikely as you have to reach 9223372036854775807 first).

Change this to `ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or better still `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`

reasons are:-

`AUTOINCREMENT` is a special case you will still get a unique identifier using `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` but without the overheads of `AUTOINCREMENT` have a read of [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)  for more info on this. `AUTOINCREMENT` can only be coded with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

If you use CursorAdapters for ListViews/Spinners they require **_id** column.

#### Note you will need to either UNINSTALL the APP, or CLEAR the App's DATA or increase the Database Version Number.

For the latter you would change :-

```
super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
```

to

```
super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 2);
```

#### Third issue

The log includes :-

```
09-09 22:42:05.219 5846-5846/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting address=ffff lastname=ffff firstname=ffff age=ffff malefemale=ffff
                                                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table friends_table has no column named address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO friends_table(address,lastname,firstname,age,malefemale) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

This includes `table friends_table has no column named address`

Although you have :-

```
private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends_table";
private static final String COL1 = "firstname";
private static final String COL2 = "lastname";
private static final String COL3 = "malefemale";
private static final String COL4 = "age";
private static final String COL5 = "address";
```

You then use the following to create the table:-

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT)";
```

This omits many of the columns instead it should be something like :-

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
    COL1 + " TEXT, " +
    COL2 + " TEXT, " +
    COL3 + " TEXT, " +
    COL4 + " INTEGER, " +
    COL5 + " TEXT)";
```

#### Note again you will need to either UNINSTALL the APP, or CLEAR the App's DATA or increase the Database Version Number.

That would work, however the `addData` method is probably not what you want. Currently it is :-

```
public boolean addData(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    //
    // 
    contentValues.put(COL1, item);
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);
    contentValues.put(COL3, item);
    contentValues.put(COL4, item);
    contentValues.put(COL5, item);

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if date as inserted inorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == 1)
        return false;
    else {
        return true;
    }


}
```

So it would make all values the same (this is reflected in the log).

It should probably be (**`was originally wrong now changed`**) :-

```
public boolean addData(String firstname, String lastname, String gender, integr age, String address) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    //
    // 
    contentValues.put(COL1, firstname);
    contentValues.put(COL2, lastname);
    contentValues.put(COL3, gender);
    contentValues.put(COL4, age);
    contentValues.put(COL5, address);

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding FirstName=" + firstname + 
        " LastName=" + lastname +
        " Gender=" + gender +
        " Age=" + Integer.toString(age) +
        " Address=" + address +
        " to " + TABLE_NAME);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if date as inserted inorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == 1)
        return false;
    else {
        return true;
    }


}
```

However, you would then also need to change wherever `addData` is used to use `addData(string_variable_with_name, string_variable_with_lastname, string_variable_with_gender, integer_variable_with_age, string_variable_with_address)`

note weird/long variable names have been used to indicate what should be used (see below for actual usage).

So in **friends.java** instead of :-

```
addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String firstName = firstnameinput.getText().toString();
                    String lastName = lastnameinput.getText().toString();
                    String age = ageinput.getText().toString();
                    String address= addressinput.getText().toString();

                    if (firstnameinput.length() !=0) {
                        AddData(firstName);
                        firstnameinput.setText("");
                    } else {
                        toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    }

                    if (lastnameinput.length() !=0) {
                        AddData(lastName);
                        lastnameinput.setText("");
                    } else {
                        toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    }

                    if (ageinput.length() !=0) {
                        AddData(age);
                        ageinput.setText("");
                    } else {
                        toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    }
                    if (addressinput.length() !=0) {
                        AddData(address);
                        addressinput.setText("");
                    } else {
                        toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    }

                }


            }); // end addbutton onclicklistener
```

you should probably have something like :-

```
    addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean addOK = true;
            int age_as_int = -1;

            String firstName = firstnameinput.getText().toString();
            String lastName = lastnameinput.getText().toString();
            String age = ageinput.getText().toString();
            String address = addressinput.getText().toString();

            if (firstName.length() < 1) {
                toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                firstnameinput.requestFocus();
                addOK = false;
            }
            if (lastName.length() < 1) {
                toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                lastnameinput.requestFocus();
                addOK = false;
            }
            if (age.length() < 1) {
                toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                ageinput.requestFocus();
                addOK = false;
            }
            if (address.length() != 0) {
                toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                addressinput.requestFocus();
                addOK = false;
            }
            try {
                age_as_int = Integer.parseInt(age);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                toastMessage("You must enter a valid Number in this field!");
                ageinput.requestFocus();
                addOK = false;
            }

            if (addOK) {
                addData(firstName,lastName,"????",age_as_int,address);
                toastMessage("Friend Added!");
            }

        }
    }); // end addbutton onclicklistener
```

Lastly change :-

```
 *// ADD DATA

    public void AddData(String firstName, String lastName, String s, int age_as_int, String newEntry) {
        boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry);

        if (insertData) {
            toastMessage("Data Successfully Added!");
        } else {
            toastMessage("Something has gone wrong :(");
        }
    }*
```

To :-

```
 // ADD DATA

public void AddData(String firstName, String lastName, String s, int age_as_int, String address) {
    boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(firstName, lastName, s,age_as_int, address);

    if (insertData) {
        toastMessage("Data Successfully Added!");
    } else {
        toastMessage("Something has gone wrong :(");
    }
}
```

Note! includes removing the **`*`** before //ADD DATA and the **`*`** after the last **`}`**

Note! in the following code, the use of **`addData`** as opposed to **`AddData`** (i.e. the one that starts with the lower case a is the one to use that actually does the insert, the one that starts with uppercase A in friends.java will then not be used so it can be deleted (AddData will be greyed out indicating that it is not used)). **Check that lower case version is used as per** :-

```
if (addOK) {
    addData(firstName,lastName,"????",age_as_int,address); //<<<<<<<<<<<<
                toastMessage("Friend Added!");
}
```

There's quite a few changes, the main one is to use the fuller form of the `addData` method (when inserting you add an entire row into the table, thus you should provide all applicable/known values). so 1 row in the table equates to all information about the friend.

The next major change is to only add a single row, so only 1 call to `AddData` once, the way you had would add a row for each valid field ending up with multiple rows all with the same data.

If an input is incorrect I've added `requestFocus()` for the input item. this will move the focus (probably) to the respective field. However, the last wrong field is where the focus would end up. You could add `return;` after **`addOK = false;`** (or even to replace `addOK = false;`), this would then immediately go to the first invalid (empty) field.

I added **`addOK`**, setting it initially to true, with any invalid fields setting it to false.

If any are false then the `addData` method will not be invoked.

**addOK** and it's checking to see if it is true would not be needed if you used `return;` to replace ALL occurrences of `addOk=false` when an input field is invalid.

Last, I added a check for age being a valid number, converting it to an integer at the same time. Again this setting **addOk** to false.

Comment: I couldn't appreciate your help more!  I tried implementing your code 

public boolean addData(String firstname, String lastname, String gender, integr age, String address) { }

In the DatabaseHelper.java file but where it has "item" is appearing as red? It can't find the reference anywhere?

Comment: oops silly me, forgot to change. post will be edited shortly.

Comment: @ccodes ok the **`addData`** method has been changed, basically item has ben changed to the respective item (firstname, lastname, gender, age & address where appropriate). Note, there is also an additional change, changing `AddData` to `addData` when calling the method (last few lines of the last block of code).

Comment: @ccodes oops ignore the change of AddData to addData, just realised that AddData in friends invokes addData in DatabaseHelper. P.S. also answered a little in the other question. I appreciate you ticking that and also upvoting this and that question.

Comment: You've been the biggest help. But I'm close I can feel it! Now just the "newEntry" string is coming up as red in the /ADD DATA section in my friends.java page. When I try to rectify the issue by changing the signature of the string (not sure if this is the correct way) it removes all strings after "String firstname" in DatabaseHelper.java.

Comment: change `boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry);` to `boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(firstName, lastName, s,  age_as_int,newEntry);`. Alternately get rid of `AddData` method in friends and change line after `if (addOK)` to use **`addData`** as opposed to AddData (the 2 very like method names is/was confusing).

Comment: I'll edit my answer accordingly, should be done soon.

Comment: If you're still having problems post all of your code, including xml here (http://shopwise.x10host.com/swf/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6&p=7#p7) if you can. I could then check everything. I need to get some shuteye now.

Comment: I couldn't appreciate it more! I posted the all the files inclusive of xmls and java to: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aec263c4986a5132b6942c5f0fa1c03f  

I tried to upload it to your link but didn't seem to work..

Comment: @ccodes I'll be posting a working/tested example shortly. pre-empted needing all the code :)

Comment: @ccodes oops added to other question. I'll get you code from github and give it a try.

Comment: @ccodes check github for fixed working version of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the TEXT PRIMARY KEY to INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT)";
```